# Load localized messages in annotations - @CsvBindByName

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations, opencsv, resourcebundle

I am trying to load localized messages from `messages.properties` in Resource Bundle into the `@CsvBindByName` annotation in `opencsv`.

My goal here is to be able to load or change values from the `messages.properties` file at anytime without changing it in the `@CsvBindByName` annotation.

This is my `MessageConfig`:

```
@Bean("messageSource")
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();

    messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalValidatorFactoryBean getValidator() {
    LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
    return bean;
}
```

I have the following properties defined in `messages.properties`:

```
global.report.customer.nbr.csv.column=Customer Number

test.error.code.mandatory=Code is mandatory
test.error.code.size=Code size must be between 1 and 5
```

I have defined the following variable in the object I want to write to my CSV file as follows:

```
@CsvBindByPosition(position = 1)
@CsvBindByName(column = "{global.report.customer.nbr.csv.column}")
private String customerNbr;
```

It outputs `{global.report.customer.nbr.csv.column}` in my CSV file instead of the message defined in my Resource Bundle.

However, if I do the same with the following annotations from `jakarta.validation.constraints`:

```
@NotNull(message = "{test.error.code.mandatory}")
@Size(min = 1, max = 5, message = "{test.error.code.size}")
```

This works fine by outputting the messages in my Resource bundle.

How can I inject values from Resource bundle into annotations such as `@CsvBindByName`?